# The "inline" keyword in C++

Tags: c++, function, inline, inline-assembly, machine-code

So the keyword "inline" will result in the call being **replaced** by the body of the function correct?
So I'm guessing that means we skip the call entirely? Like if we look at the .asm file we wouldn't find a call instruction?

Comment: inline is a suggestion to the compiler to consider it for inlinning. If it does get inlined, all calls to the function get replaced with the body of the function.

Comment: The main use of `inline` to a modern C++ compiler is avoidance of violating the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: It's case by case, most compilers can emit a warning if they fail to `inline` something.

Comment: @Taekahn so at the assembly instruction lvl, we dont see any call instructions right?

Comment: Here is a good read about inline functions https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions

Comment: @ヅヅヅ yes, **IF** a function gets inlined, then there is no call instruction used at the site where the function is called from. The function's actual body code is inserted directly into the call site instead, as if there were no function present.

Comment: @ヅヅヅ • the `inline` keyword is just a suggestion.  It's pretty much superfluous these days, for the purpose of inlining, since the compiler will decide that on its own.  The general purpose in C++ these days is to allow putting a routine in a header file without violating ODR.

Answer (score 5):

Keyword `inline` is misleading - it is neither necessary nor sufficient for actual inlining to happen. All it does: it tells the linker to allow multiple definitions of the function, which means you can place the function in a header. Once you do it, the compiler has a better chance to inline since the function body becomes visible in more places. In modern systems, it is not important anymore if they use whole code optimization.

Once the compiler has a chance to inline, it has to decide whether it is beneficial for whatever optimization you asked it to do (e.g. optimize for speed).

If the compiler decides to inline, then what you say about .asm file is correct - no call of the function.

Comment: So it depends on type of optimization. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @ヅヅヅ better wording would be "it is *influenced* by the type of optimization." The compiler will be looking at a bunch of different metrics like, "Will inlining the function wreck the instruction cache and take longer?"

Answer (score 0):

> So the keyword "inline" will result in the call being replaced by the body of the function correct?

Incorrect.

> So I'm guessing that means we skip the call entirely? Like if we look at the .asm file we wouldn't find a call instruction?

Yes, if compiler expands a function call inline, then there will not be a function call indeed.

But the `inline` keyword does not mean that calls to the function are guaranteed to be expanded inline.