# How to pass a method of an object instance to a std::function type callback?

Tags: c++

The `evpp` library has a callback method with following signature,

```
void evpp::TCPServer::SetMessageCallback(evpp::MessageCallback cb)
```

`evpp::MessageCallback` is in fact,

```
typedef std::function<void(const TCPConnPtr&, Buffer*)> MessageCallback;
```

I have a non-static method called `worker` inside `HTTPTransport` class and it has below signature ,

```
void worker(const evpp::TCPConnPtr& conn, evpp::Buffer* msg, AnotherObject &instanceOfThat);
```

I attempt to attach this function into callback as follows,

```
evpp::EventLoop loop;
evpp::TCPServer server(&loop, "0.0.0.0:9000", "HTTPServer", 5);

HTTPTransport HTTPInterface;
AnotherObject instanceOfThat;

server.SetMessageCallback(std::bind(&HTTPTransport::worker, &HTTPInterface, &instanceOfThat));
```

But the compiler says,

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::__2::__bind<void (HTTPTransport::*)(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, evpp::Buffer *msg, AnotherObject &instanceOfThat), HTTPTransport *, AnotherObject*>" to "evpp::MessageCallback" exists
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to bind the evpp::Buffer* msg?

Comment: @N.Prone No. That one passed by the lib itself.

Comment: Have you considered using a (capturing) lambda, instead of `std::bind`?

Comment: If you insist on using `std::bind` rather than a lambda, then you need a placeholder in its argument list - see the example from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: @Eugene Do I have to put it for every each arg? The callback function only accepts two args so my worker function accepts three args....

Comment: Is that the first error you get? I tried mocking up the missing pieces, and the first thing my compiler complained about was `static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member` (which more directly complains about your lack of placeholders).

Comment: As suggested in an answer, I would always use a lambda unless you have a free (or static member function) that exactly match.

Comment: @Eugene I was reading your answer, but why did you delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `std::bind()`, you have to include *placeholders* for the arguments you are passing. Also, using `&` for the last argument is incorrect - what you need instead is `std::ref()`. Your expression becomes:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2
server.SetMessageCallback(std::bind(&HTTPTransport::worker, &HTTPInterface, _1, _2, std::ref(instanceOfThat)));
```

However, using a lambda is easier:

```
   server.SetMessageCallback([&](const TCPConnPtr& ptr, Buffer* buf)
   {
        return HTTPInterface.worker(ptr, buf, instanceOfThat); 
   } );
```

Comment: Are lambdas faster than bind in terms of perf?

Comment: To notice any difference, `worker()` would need to be *really* fast. My guess lambda could be a bit faster if  `worker()` is inlined, otherwise about the same.

Comment: I thought -O3 take care about inline. Do I have to mark function as inline using inline keyword?

Comment: It is a complicated topic - see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62924502/459565. Generally, do not add `inline` if your project builds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I severely dislike std::bind. I always use a lambda. This might work:

```
void worker(const evpp::TCPConnPtr& conn, evpp::Buffer* msg) {
    ...
}

server.SetMessageCallback([=](const evpp::TCPConnPtr & conn, evpp::Buffer * buffer){ worker(conn, buffer); });
```

Your worker method then is just a standard method on your object. Get rid of the 3rd argument.

Comment: How would one so simply get rid of a parameter of type `AnotherObject &` in a method belonging to class `HTTPTransport`? How are you calling `worker` without a `HTTPTransport` object?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding some of what you're doing. I was writing as if worker is in the current object. If not, just do anotherObject->worker() in the lambda instead.

Comment: OP has worker() function with 3 args, not 2.

Comment: @Eugene Yes -- I interpreted that as the class holding the method he's working on, but in a lambda, you can make use of it immediately. I may be misunderstanding his use case, but the mechanism is still valid.

Comment: It looks like you've misread two parts of the question. **First,** the classes `HTTPTransport` and `AnotherObject` are *different classes*. You cannot replace the `AnotherObject&` parameter to `worker` with the `HTTPTransport` object through which `worker` should be called. Dropping that parameter is a problem. **Second,** `worker` is a *non-static method of a class*. You cannot call `worker` without an object of that class. This is why the question defines `HTTPInterface` and binds that object to `HTTPTransport::worker`. You've dropped this object, which is a problem.